# How to add quotes in an argument when passing to a function in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, quotes

I need to add '"$third'" these quotes to a argument to get the right result.
Below is the code i have

`$first = Function-xyz $second $third`

Here somehow if we can add '"$third"' and pass the argument it will work for me, but can do that with below approach

`$first = Function-xyz $second '"$third"'`

With this it just pass third itself as a string without reading its value.

Comment: Reverse the order of quotes `"'$third'"`.  When the double-quotes are on the outside the variable will get expanded.  Single-quotes are the opposite and do not expand variables.

Comment: Also, if you really want double-quotes surrounding your value you can do "\`"$third\`"" (use backtick to escape the double-quote \`" or `"""$third"""`

Comment: Adding like ""$third"" worked , Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome.

Here's how I would do it:

```
$third = "Some Text"
Return '"{0}"' -f $third
```

at the end of your function. This will expand the value of Third: "Some text"

If you would do this:

```
$Third = '$Second'
Return '"{0}"' -f $third
```

It would result in: "$Second"

If you would do this:

```
$Second = 2
$Third = "$Second"
Return '"{0}"' -f $third
```

It would result in: 2

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question then.